# Creating a simple javascript concatenator

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I'd like to create a simple javascript concatenator that takes 2 HTML `textarea` tags as input, and concatenates each line from textarea 1 with each line from textarea 2.

So I think I'm basically looking for a javascript function that will generate an array from the textarea, where each new line delimits a new element in the array, like so:

```
Textbox:
item 1\n
item 2\n
item 3
```

becomes...

```
["item 1","item 2","item 3"]
```

How do I do that? I could do this pretty easily in php, but js mystifies me. If anyone can share the code that would do this, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var ary = (
    document.getElementById('yourTextArea1').value +
    document.getElementById('yourTextArea2').value
).split('\n');
```

throw an extra `+ '\n'` between those if desired

Comment: That only does one textbox. OP has two.

Comment: Wouldn't this create one long list of all values from both? So if text1 is "one \n two" and text2 is "a \n b" I want to return "one a, one b, two a, two b". I think this would return "one, two, a, b" - right? The split function is what I was looking for though so big thanks, I think I just need to create 2 separate arrays, and then use a for loop to concatenate each line from text1 with each lines of text2.

Comment: @Chris - sorry I mis-understood your question.  Yes, just create two arrays and loop them both; it seems like you know what you're doing in general :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> var str = "1\n2\n3 4";
>
> var strArray = str.split("\n");

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray =(document.getElementById('a').value+document.getElementById('b').value).split('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use what @cwolves provided, but it might not work on PCs that use a carriage return instead of a line feed. Here's a script that fixes that and also can join all textareas:

```
var ta=document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
var vals=[];
for(var i=0;i<ta.length;i++){
    vals.push(ta.value.replace(/\r\n|\n\r/gim,"\n").replace(/\r/gim,"\n");
}
var val=vals.join("\n")
var ary=val.split("\n");
```

So here the textareas on the page are put into the "ta" variable, then we replace carriage returns with line feeds. The result of it being split into an array is in the "ary" variable.

Ad@m